# Erase to Transparency

Tags: c#, gdi+

So I'm trying to make a 32x32 block back to transparent but everytime I try to set it to transparent it just keeps what ever is already there, I want to erase what's on the image to transparent, here's my code I tried.

```
    public Bitmap erase_tile(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y)
    {
        Graphics device = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, Color.White));

        device.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32));
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)`?

Comment: Transparent is kind of "fake" it takes the colour of the object behind it

Comment: Depends on if you're drawing a transparent color or setting the pixels equal to the transparent color. I'm not totally sure which one of those `Graphics.Clear()` does.

Comment: @Michael_Gunter, Graphics.Clear clears the whole image I just want one 32x32 part of the image to be cleared

Comment: Nothing seriously wrong with this code.  So it is probably what you do next that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All transparency is going to be accomplished via functionality on the `Bitmap` class. The `Graphics` class is geared toward *drawing*, and drawing `Color.Transparent` is essentially a no-op.

You can use `Bitmap.SetPixel()` with `Color.Transparent` to set individual pixels.

Or you can do something like this, where you use `Graphics` to paint a dummy color which you will then instruct the bitmap to use as the transparent color.

```
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 64, 64);
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Magenta, 16, 16, 32, 32);
}
bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Magenta);
```

Comment: hmm I see, I can test this out in a bit I'm working with creating layers at the moment give me maybe 10 min and ill try it out

Comment: Thanks :D I'll give it a test in a sec :)

Comment: It works :) I'd give you +1 but I don't have 15 rep yet. Thanks though!

Comment: I think you can mark my answer as correct without any reputation.

Answer (score 1):

While I was searching for the same solution, I wasn't able to find the exact answer, so after some experiments I came across `SetCompositingMode` and it made the trick (refer to [Using Compositing Mode to Control Alpha Blending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533955(v=vs.85).aspx) for full details).

Here is a working code in C++ to demonstrate the approach (it needs some tuning to be re-used in C#):

```
void SetTransparent(Gdiplus::Image* image, IN INT x, IN INT y, IN INT width, IN INT height)
{
    Gdiplus::Graphics graph(image);
    graph.SetCompositingMode(Gdiplus::CompositingModeSourceCopy);
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush transparent(0);
    graph.FillRectangle(&transparent, x, y, width, height);
}
```