# Can we do erase to transparency in Windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Actually i am wondering to erase an image to transparency. like i have an image on page background and another image above that. Now i want that if i erase above image by finger then lower image should be appear, simply means to say image will become transparent.i'm doing something like this but its not meet my requirements.
Your suggestions are Welcome :)

```
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{

    currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this.canvas);
    //Initialize line according to currentpoint position.
    Line line = new Line() 
                { 
                    X1 = currentPoint.X, 
                    Y1 = currentPoint.Y, 
                    X2 = oldPoint.X, 
                    Y2 =oldPoint.Y 
                };          


    line.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round;
    line.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
    line.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
    line.StrokeThickness = 20;
    line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) ;
    ////////////////////////////////
    //Set color & thickness of line. 

    //Line add in canvas children to draw image & assign oldpoint.
    this.canvas.Children.Add(line);
    oldPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

Comment: Sounds kinda like duplicate of this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073357/erase-to-transparency

Comment: @walther no, it isn't. It's XAML, not GDI.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 3 different ways:

1. Using opaque overlay and `UIElement.Clip` property. But you need to deal with `Geometry`. And I'm afraid it will be very CPU cost.
2. Using `WriteableBitmap` and changing an alpha channel of image. You can do it using [`WriteableBitmapEx`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwriteablebitmapex.codeplex.com%2F&ei=X0cIVP6gLeL5yQOiooHICA&usg=AFQjCNFIO9hY-elZhLB_UnJcTzWKGFOGAA&bvm=bv.74649129,d.bGQ).
3. Using opaque overlay and `UIElement.OpacityMask` property. I think it's the best way to accomplish that, as you're not limited to use bitmap (so you can place any XAML control below overlay) as in the second way.

Comment: Thankx Eldar!! I appreciate you :)  can you explain more it please, i'm new in windows Phone development..